# Is that possible to replace an element with specific content with a same element with another content with only CSS?

Tags: css

I have a list of data that comes from the server, What I want is to replace only the `span` with `class="more-info"` which only have "," as its data, and keep it empty. Is that possible with only the CSS?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="performance-list list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <div class="date">
                <span class="month-date-year">13. Sep, 2018</span>
                <span class="weekday">xxx</span>
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                <h3>xx xx</h3>
                <span class="name2">xx xxx xxx. xxx</span>
                <span class="more-info">20:00 Uhr / xxxxxx</span>
            </div>   
            <div class="action">            
                <a href="/xxx" class="btn btn-default">Tickets</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="date">
                <span class="month-date-year">23. Sep, 2018</span>
                <span class="weekday">xxx</span>
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                <h3>xx xx xx xxx</h3>
                <span class="name2">xx xxx</span>
                <span class="more-info">, </span>
            </div>
            <div class="action">            
                <a href="xxx" class="btn btn-default">Tickets</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this using javascript

Comment: But you can't do with with just CSS

Comment: what you want to replace span class.more-info , with the tag?

Comment: -Morteza Fathnia i want to hide the span with class more-info only when content " , " .  And keep the same span class  who have anything else,